# How to check syntax errors of a Python module with unknown imports

Tags: python, interpreter, python-import

I want to invoke the Python interpreter to check possible syntax errors of my module.
I can't do it because the interpreter generates an early error message of

```
ImportError: No module named Part
```

In my module I have imported a module that is needed in my code.

```
import Part

def draw_circle(radius):
    myshape = Part.makeSphere(1)
    Part.show(myshape)
    return
```

The imported `Part` module belongs to FreeCAD in my case but my question is general.  Let's assume that we don't know the module library directory path of the module `Part`.

When in FreeCAD I import my syntactically correct module everything runs without problems.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/mypathtomymodule')
import mymodule

mymodule.draw_circle(1)
```

There is no problem as long as I write proper syntax code. Unfortunately I don't always do that. In those cases my problem is that I can not search for the syntax errors in my module with the Python interpreter. Also the FreeCAD is not very helpful here, When I try to run the program in FreeCAD it gives an uninformative error message like

```
NameError: name 'badcode' is not defined
```

Comment: These are *runtime exceptions*, not syntax errors.

Comment: I've read your question three times, and I don't see the connection between these pieces of code and the three different kinds of errors (Syntax, Import, Name) at all. Can you clarify? For example, if you import a module that contains a syntax error, you should be getting a `SyntaxError` exception as well, so I don't see your problem.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, however? Your code doesn't run; catching the exception won't make it run any better, just suppress the error here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I wanted to be able to check for possible syntax errors. That is what I wanted to achieve. I'm sorry if I was not clear. I don't understand your comment about catching exceptions. I didn't ask about exceptions.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, thanks for your effort to try to help me. Obviously I failed in emphasizing the problem. It was not in the code snippets, they are ok, they run without problems. My problem was a general one, how to check for syntax errros, or any other errors that usually are found when invoking the interpreter. I didn't know how to do it for a module in case when the module contains an unresolvable import statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `python -m py_compile mymodule.py`. This produces a byte code file, but can be used to check for syntax errors in the process.